# Formation of a bitonal image by the threshold Thr

Tags: matlab, signals, digital

I have a task - The formation of a bitonal image on the threshold of Thr. If the pixel brightness value exceeds the threshold, then it is replaced by the maximum (in our case by 255), otherwise by the minimum, i.e. by 0. But at the output, the image behaves strangely from the side, tell me how to fix it?

[The result obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMXfl.png)

```
function decomp_new(array, thr, filename, FH, IH, RGBQUAD0, RGBQUAD1)
    FID = fopen(filename, 'w');
    
    fwrite(FID, FH.bfTYPE, 'uchar');
    fwrite(FID, FH.bfSIZE, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, FH.bfR1, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, FH.bfR2, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, FH.bfOFFBITS, 'ulong');
    
    fwrite(FID, IH.biSIZE, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.biWIDTH, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.biHEIGHT, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.biPLANES, 'uint16');
    fwrite(FID, 1, 'uint16'); %IH.biBITCOUNT
    fwrite(FID, IH.biCOMPRESSION, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.biSIZEIMAGE, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.biXPELSPERMETER, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.biYPELSPERMETER, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.biCLRUSED, 'ulong'); %IH.biCLRUSED
    fwrite(FID, IH.biCLRIMPORTANT, 'ulong');
    fwrite(FID, IH.tmp, 'uint8');
    
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD0.RED, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD0.GREEN, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD0.BLUE, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD0.RESERVED, 'uint8');
    
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD1.RED, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD1.GREEN, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD1.BLUE, 'uint8');
    fwrite(FID, RGBQUAD1.RESERVED, 'uint8');

    for i = 1 : 3 : length(array)
        B = array(i);
        G = array(i+1);
        R = array(i+2);
        Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B;
        if (Y > thr)
            fwrite(FID, 1, 'ubit1','ieee-be');
        end
        if (Y <= thr)
            fwrite(FID, 0, "ubit1','ieee-be');
        end
    end
    fclose(FID);
end
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly what is different about the image output that you got from what you expected?  Also, you have a syntax error in this line: `fwrite(FID, 0, "ubit1','ieee-be');` Mismatched quote types.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).